# ScheduledToastNotification Not Show If DeliveryTime Missed

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10

I'm targetting `Windows 10`  `Build 10586`.

Using `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` library to build this Toast :

```
   ToastContent content = new ToastContent()
    {
        Launch = "@remider",

        Visual = new ToastVisual()
        {
            BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
            {
                Children =
                        {
                            new AdaptiveText()
                            {
                                Text = "This is Toast"
                            },

                            new AdaptiveText()
                            {
                                Text = "This is toast content"
                            }
                        },
                AppLogoOverride = new ToastGenericAppLogo()
                {
                    Source = "ms-appx:///Assets/Toast/Toast.png",
                }
            },
        },
        Scenario = ToastScenario.Reminder,
        Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
        {
            Buttons =
                    {
                        new ToastButton("Open App", "@remider:1"),
                        new ToastButton("Dismiss", "cancel"){ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Background}
                    }
        }
    };

var remiderTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(15);

ToastNotifier toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
toastNotifier.AddToSchedule(new ScheduledToastNotification(content.GetXml(), remiderTime));
```

Say that reminderTime is `10:00 AM`, and I shutdown my PC at `09:58 AM` and turn on my PC again at `10:15 AM`, no Toast shown because it's missed the `Delivery Time` (`10:00 AM`) because I turn off my PC at that time.

I want the Toast is show even the Delivery Time is missed.
How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Say that reminderTime is 10:00 AM, and I shutdown my PC at 09:58 AM and turn on my PC again at 10:15 AM, no Toast shown because it's missed the Delivery Time (10:00 AM) because I turn off my PC at that time

This is by design. If the client device has missed the delivery time due to power off, the toast notification will not be delivered again.

I've sent your requirement to the related team to see if this is an acceptable feature request.

**------Update--------**

**This issue has been filed in here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/platform/bugs/11030032
You can see the status**

Comment: Hello, the link is not active now